# Problem Deploying Shiny App to shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

Running the following code to deploy a very simple Shiny app onto `shinyapps.io`:

```
rm(list = ls())

library(shiny)
library(rsconnect)

ui <- fluidPage("Hello World",
                sliderInput(inputId = "num",
                            label = "Choose a Number",
                            value = 25,
                            min = 1,
                            max = 100),
                plotOutput("hist"))

server <- function(input, output)
{

  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$num))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='xxx redacted xxx', token='xxx redacted xxx', secret='xxx redacted xxx')
rsconnect::deployApp(".") # we're already in the correct directory
```

It's not working. I can see the app from my `shinyapps.io` dashboard, but when I try to launch it in my web browser, I get a spinning wheel and eventually a message:

```
Attaching package: ‘rsconnect’

The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:

serverInfo

Error in value[[3L]](cond) : HTTP 409 POST https://api.shinyapps.io/v1/applications/2371290/deploy Unable to dispatch task for application=2371290, there are 1 tasks in progress Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous> Execution halted
```

appears. Can anyone help with this please? I've never done this before and I'm a little confused.

Running Microsoft R Client 3.5.2/RStudio 1.3/Windows 10.

Thank you.

EDIT: log file contents...

```
2020-05-28T14:51:42.591212+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: R version: 3.5.2
2020-05-28T14:51:42.591131+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: Server version: 1.8.2.1-12
2020-05-28T14:51:42.591211+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: LANG: en_US.UTF-8
2020-05-28T14:51:42.591213+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: shiny version: 1.2.0
2020-05-28T14:51:42.591213+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: httpuv version: 1.4.5.1
2020-05-28T14:51:42.591213+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: rmarkdown version: (none)
2020-05-28T14:51:42.591226+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: knitr version: (none)
2020-05-28T14:51:42.708336+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: 
2020-05-28T14:51:42.591349+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc2
2020-05-28T14:51:42.704612+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2020-05-28T14:51:42.591226+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: RJSONIO version: (none)
2020-05-28T14:51:42.591226+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: jsonlite version: 1.6
2020-05-28T14:51:42.591226+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: htmltools version: 0.3.6
2020-05-28T14:51:42.708337+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: Starting R with process ID: '25'
2020-05-28T14:51:42.746463+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: 
2020-05-28T14:51:42.747094+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: 
2020-05-28T14:51:42.747093+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:
2020-05-28T14:51:42.747094+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]:     serverInfo
2020-05-28T14:51:42.746464+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: Attaching package: ‘rsconnect’
2020-05-28T14:51:42.746465+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: 
2020-05-28T14:51:42.747094+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: 
2020-05-28T14:51:43.101717+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: Preparing to deploy application...DONE
2020-05-28T14:51:46.026109+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: Uploading bundle for application: 2371290...DONE
2020-05-28T14:51:46.032758+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: Deploying bundle: 3200741 for application: 2371290 ...
2020-05-28T14:51:46.480750+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]: Waiting for task: 738249988
2020-05-28T14:51:47.584835+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]:   building: Processing bundle: 3200741
2020-05-28T14:51:48.625497+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]:   building: Parsing manifest
2020-05-28T14:51:49.670153+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]:   building: Building image: 3578706
2020-05-28T14:51:50.755095+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]:   building: Fetching packages
2020-05-28T14:51:51.803751+00:00 shinyapps[2371290]:   building: Installing packages
```

Comment: Have a look at these for 409 error
https://community.rstudio.com/t/deploying-content-to-connect-throws-409-conflict/37707/4 and https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-http-409-when-deploying/49412

Comment: Not sure what it all means! However I cloned the project directory and ran everything from scratch and now something different is happening (but still with a 409 error). OP edited to reflect this.

Comment: And now a different error when I try to run the app again...

Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  Unhandled Exception: Child Task 738255782 error: Unhandled Exception: Error pushing repository: received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error

Is this a bug at their end?

Comment: Does the file that you upload as app include the two last statements `rsconnect::setAccountInfo` and `rsconnect::deployApp`?

Comment: Yes. Is that a mistake? Should I remove them from the app.R script and just type them at the console instead?

Comment: Seems to have fixed the problem...thank you